# Не могу найти ошибка в задаче на выравнивание абзаца

Tags: c

Условие задачи:

*Дано натуральное число K и строка текста, состоящая из слов, отделенных пробелами. Требуется разбить входную строку на строки длины K. В очередной строке должно быть выведено максимальное количество очередных слов входной строки, которые целиком помещаются в строку длины K (при условии, что слова разделены хотя бы одним пробелом). При этом, требуется каждую выходную строку отформатировать следующим образом. Необходимо, чтобы среднеквадратическое отклонение длин пробельных серий в каждой такой строке было минимальным (пробельная серия - непрерывная последовательность пробелов между двумя словами). То есть, если в строке есть n пробельных серий длины li и среднее арифметическое этих длин равно L, то среднее арифметическое величин (li - L)^2 должно быть минимально для результирующей строки.*

*Если в строку входит больше одного слова, дополнять пробелами разрешается только промежутки между двумя словами. При возможности добавить пробел в несколько промежутков, выбирать следует тот промежуток, который расположен ближе всего к началу строки. Если же только одно очередное слово входной строки входит в очередную выходную строку, то необходимо вывести сначала это слово, а потом дополнить длину очередной выходной строки пробелами до K символов.*

*На стандартном потоке ввода в первой строке задано число K (K ≥ 1, K ≤ 10^6), во второй строке задана последовательность символов (строка) S, состоящая из пробелов и букв латинского алфавита, признак окончания которой - символ перевода строки. Известно, что длина строки S ≤ 10^6. Строка состоит из слов, разделенных пробельными символами (по одному пробелу между двумя словами). Строка начинается и кончается словами, либо является одним словом. В строке содержится по крайней мере одно слово. Известно, что любое слово входной последоватьности имеет длину не больше K.*

*На стандартный поток вывода напечатайте результат описанного выше преобразования. Каждую выходную строку следует завершать символом перевода строки '\n'.*

Вот мое решение, язык C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_line(int k, char w[1000002][k + 2], int l, int r) {
    int amount_w = r - l + 1;
    int w_len = 0;
    for (int i = l; i <= r; ++i)
        w_len += strlen(w[i]);
    int amount_sp = k - w_len;
    int curr_sum = 0;
    printf("%s", w[l]);
    for (int i = 0; i < amount_w - 1; ++i) {
        int x = (amount_sp - curr_sum) / (amount_w - 1 - i);
        if ((amount_sp - curr_sum) % (amount_w - 1 - i))
            ++x;
        curr_sum += x;
        for (int j = 0; j < x; ++j)
            printf(" ");
        printf("%s", w[l + i + 1]);
    }
    if (r == l) {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount_sp; ++i)
            printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    int k;
    scanf("%d\n", &k);
    char s[1000002];
    fgets(s, 1000002, stdin);
    if (s[strlen(s) - 1] == '\n')
        s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';
    int amount = 0, curr = 0;
    char w[1000002][k + 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); ++i) {
        if (s[i] != ' ') {
            w[amount][curr++] = s[i];
        } else {
            w[amount++][curr] = '\0';
            curr = 0;
        }
    }
    ++amount;
    int len_curr = 0, l_curr = 0, r_curr = 0;
    while (l_curr < amount) {
        len_curr += strlen(w[l_curr]);
        r_curr = l_curr;
        while (r_curr < amount - 1) {
            int t = strlen(w[r_curr + 1]);
            if (len_curr + 1 + t > k) {
                break;
            }
            len_curr += 1 + t;
            ++r_curr;
        }
        if (r_curr == amount)
            --r_curr;
        print_line(k, w, l_curr, r_curr);
        l_curr = r_curr + 1;
        len_curr = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

В функции main я сначала считываю число и строку, потом создаю массив слов. После в цикле нахожу, сколько слов помещается в очередную строку и передаю левую и правую границу в функцию print_line, которая печатает очередную строку, считая, сколько пробелов нужно между словами.

Мое решение проходит 10 тестов в системе, а потом происходит "Ошбика выполнения". Мне сказали, что это либо деление на 0, либо выход за границы массива. Но ни того, ни другого я у себя никак не могу найти.

Я пробовал менять размер массивов, увеличивая его, но это не дало никакого эффекта.

Мой друг, успешно решивший эту задачу немного по-другому, проверил результаты наших программ на множестве небольших тестов и не нашел в них ошибок.

Comment: Вы преднамеренно здесь: `char w[1000002][k + 2];` используете VLA массив? Вы уверены, что при этом не сносите стек при определенных значениях `k`?

Comment: Не уверен. Видимо лучше не создавать такой массив слов, он получается слишком большой, должно быть, и не влезает в ограничения.

Comment: Если нужен большой массив, то лучше создайте его как динамический на куче. А так... Размер стека, если правильно помню, по умолчанию 2 Мб для 32-битной Windows и 8Мб для 64-битной. А у Вас там одна размерность в массиве примерно 1 Мб...

Comment: Вообще ограничение по памяти в этой задаче 64М стоит, по времени 1 с

Comment: Ну так это же, наверное, ограничение на суммарный объем памяти: и на стеке, и в куче. Не думаю, что они ради Вас будут специально выделять 64Мб именно для стека...

Comment: В этой задаче еще подразумевается, что мы не знаем про динамическую память. Задачи на нее появятся в следующих контестах. 
Спасибо за помощь, пойду перепишу задачу без массива этого

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116358/discussion-between-vladimir-and-dg-mishee).

Answer (score 0):

А зачем Вами все эти гигантские массивы?! (char w[1000002][k + 2]) Я эту задачу решал ещё на ЕС-1022 у которой вся память была 128 КБ (КИЛО байт!!!) Только там были условия маленько посложнее - надо было учитывать отступ в первой строке абзаца и т.н. "повисшие строки" - попадание последней строки абзаца на следующую страницу.

Ну а по сути. Единственный массив, который нужен для решения этой задачи - массив символов, длиной в одну строку документа. В вашем задании написано, что строка может быть длиной в миллион символов. По моему, это бред, но всё равно - выделить один мегабайт памяти не составляет проблемы.

А дальше алгоритм такой:

1. Читаем последовательно **слова** из входного потока.
2. Каждое введённое слово размещаем в выходной буфер с интервалом в один пробел.
3. Если очередное введённое слово **не** помещается, запоминаем его и выполняем форматирование по правилам, которые Вы используете.
4. После этого сбрасываем выходной буфер и помещаем в него запомненное слово.
5. Возвращаемся к п. 1.

Форматирование тоже не требует никаких особых затрат памяти:

1. Повторяем до тех пор, пока в выходном буфере есть пробелы справа
2. Переходим на конец очередного слова и вставляем там пробел

При таком алгоритме правило распределения пробелов, которое установлено в Вашем задании, выполняется автоматически. Здесь не учитывается последняя строка абзаца, но у Вас этого нет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, решил в итоге примерно так же без массива